# Way of shortening border left right bottom?

Tags: css, border

Just a short question

Is there a shorter way of writing this code so that all 3 are covered in one rule?

`border-left: 2px solid #006699;
border-right: 2px solid #006699;
border-bottom: 2px solid #006699;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [border shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Border_Properties) and then set `border-top` to `none`. [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/NkjUx/)

```
border: 2px solid #006699;
border-top: none;
```

Comment: Thanks thats a lot shorter